# React presentational (stateless) component using input tags without state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to follow a simple presentation model i.e. it has no state.

Problem being is that if I use a Input tag or other form control, the only way for that component to update itself is using state - is this correct?

This means, that any component that has just 1 input tag would be forced to be a stateful component rather than a stateless - just because of the way react works and getting the input tag to update while the user is typing.

Is there an alternative ?

Although I am using hooks which is cleaner and allows me to use a functional component by the use of "useState" - it still is going to be stateful.

Now that hooks came along - are we saying that all functional components can hold state ? It doesn't seem right.

Or is it just the case that due to the way react works that any component that has an input tag automatically becomes a stateful component ?

Of course what I could do is pass down default values via props and pass up the values to a higher component (my real stateful component) - but this seems kind of a long way round a doing this.

I was hoping for some insight on what should be a way to achieve a stateless component that has a input tag - or should we always pass values back to the parent component, or its a understood side effect that when a component has a input tag we would store minimal state (using useState for example, in hooks)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uncontrolled components

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.input.current.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" ref={this.input} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

These use refs to get the current value of input rather than maintaining a a state for it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of managing that input in the component, you should pass a callback to it, eg. a redux store or alike. This way the form component is decoupled from the logic behind that input and becomes simply a presentational one:

```
const Form = callback => {
    const inputRef = React.createRef();

    const handleInput = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        callback(inputRef.current.value);
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleInput}>
            <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```